# load pull in ads

Tags: mosfet, rf, ads, power-amplifier

I am trying to do a load pull simulation using ADS for push pull FET power amplifier .

First I used the ADS one tone palette to simulate one of the FET's:
[image]
Then I found the optimum input and output load for all different frequencies:
[image]
Then i doubled the impedance I found to move to balanced configuration and this is the impedance I used to match the PA:
for example: 2*(3.93+j0.977)=7.86+j1.954

Question: **Is there a direct load pull simulation for balanced FET's that the 2 FET's are connected together to one differential load and source?**

Dan.

Comment: Your question appears to be about potential facilities in ADS and that rather confuses me given the two pictures in your question. This makes your question "unclear what you're asking" and potentially subject to closure. Maybe you can make things clearer?

Comment: Are you using the LoadPull design guide from ADS or are you making your own load pull?

Comment: Yes I am  using the LoadPull design guide. but the design  guide only work on single FET and I need 2 FET's in balanced configuration

Comment: Is your question regarding whether to  apply load pull to single transistor or both transistors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use ideal baluns for that.

[image]

Comment: Does this work for higher frequencies?

Comment: I will try it thanks

Comment: I've used ideal baluns above to provide a first-approach template to evaluate how the push-pull arrangement works. However, you'll need to replace them by the s-parameter file of your real-life balun later. 
Concerning  the practical implementation, traditional (wired) baluns can work up to 1.2-1.5GHz. See e.g. http://www.minirf.com/pdf/transformers/MRFXF0035DS.pdf
On the other hand, I'm aware that progress has been made in designing microwave push-pull amplifiers using transmission line baluns. See, for example, this thesis https://core.ac.uk/display/20075325

Comment: @Dan:  I think you can also use TLINP4 instead of balun  in ADS simulation.

Comment: @Andrés Martínez Mera: Thank you for your answer and link for Thesis.

Answer (score 1):

I think  there is no ready ADS template for push pull type configuration. Either you need to use  single ended template and double  the impedance or design your own load pull setup for this type of configuration.